# how do I add godaddy cert to my azure web app?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

The question is about godaddy and Azure.

I have a azure 'web app' .
And I bought a domain name from go-daddy.
Do I need to ask go-daddy for a phx? Is that same as  SSL certificate type  Standard SSL DV ?
And then go  to  azure portal /Web ap/ TLS/ssl settings, and import a PHX t?
Thanks,Peter

Comment: What is phx？ You can get .pfx or .crt files from go-daddy and add cert to you azure web app. Now maybe something wrong with go-daddy, you also can apply SSL from other sites.

Comment: I found that the current domain name resolution function of go-daddy is abnormal. You can use a network service provider like Alipay or Tencent to host DNS and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

I have try to create [demo website](https://panshubei.live)  for u. You can follow my steps to solve the issues. You can add Custom domains in portal, like below screen shots.

[image]

[image]

You need to perform DNS domain name resolution, and then apply for an SSL certificate.

[image]

After you have .pfx/.crt files, Click `Add Binding`,then upload your file, choose SSL Types value is SNI SSL.

Set here, your azure web URL has been set to your domain name, `TLS/SSL` settings are required below. Make the website trustworthy.

[image]

You can click `TLS/SSL settings`. You can refer the [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate).Click `TLS/SSL SETTINGS`->`Private Key Certificates(.pfx)`->`+Upload Certificate`->Select .pfx file and input your password. Then back to 'Custom domains',make sure `HTTPS Only` is on.

By setting you will see the following effect.

[image]